# How to map Github GraphQL API commit responses to react-bootstrap Cards?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap, react-apollo, github-api-v4

All the following code is in a custom component titled CommitCards.

Given the following gql query using [React Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/).

```
const GET_REPO_COMMITS = gql`
query GetRepoCommits($repoName: String!) {
  repository(name: $repoName, owner: "FernandoH-G") {
    defaultBranchRef {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          history(first: 5) {
            edges {
              node {
                pushedDate
                message
                url
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`;

const repoName = props.rName
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_REPO_COMMITS, {
        variables: { repoName },
    });
    if (loading) return (
        <p>Loading...</p>
    );
    if (error) return (
        <p>Error.</p>
    );
```

I am able to get the last 5 commits from a given repository belonging to the given owner.

Given by the nature of how GraphQL's JSON response is structured, I feel the need to do the following:

```
    const commits = data.repository.defaultBranchRef.target.history.edges
    const innerCommits = commits.map(com =>(
        com.node
    ))
```

Neither mapping over commits or innerCommits using more or less the following react-strap Card code:

```
    return commits.map(com => {
        <Card 
        key={com.node.url}
        border="info">
            <Card.Body>
                <Card.Header as="h4"> {com.node.pushDate} </Card.Header>
                <Card.Text> {com.node.message}</Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    })
```

renders the cards on the screen.

Note that using the following test html does display the proper information, just as a single long string.

```
return(
        <p>{commits.map( a => (
            a.node.message
        ))}</p>
    )
```

The component is called here:

```
            <CardDeck>
                <CommitCards rName={value} />
            </CardDeck>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out...

```
  return commits.map(com => {
        <Card 
        key={com.node.url}
        border="info">
            <Card.Body>
                <Card.Header as="h4"> {com.node.pushDate} </Card.Header>
                <Card.Text> {com.node.message}</Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    })
```

should have been this:

```
  return commits.map(com => (
        <Card 
        key={com.node.url}
        border="info">
            <Card.Body>
                <Card.Header as="h4"> {com.node.pushDate} </Card.Header>
                <Card.Text> {com.node.message}</Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    ))
```

Note the ( vs the { .

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the Bootstrap CSS that is required.

Add this import somewhere towards the top level of your app, like `index.js` or `App.js`:

`import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";`

See more: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#stylesheets

Comment: I do have the CSS imported. 
In the parent component where the CommitCards is rendered, I already do something similar to this. The component is RepoCards and I have them nested in a CardDeck as well. The cards render fine.